# Razor TextBoxFor name and value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

How do I do this using Razor?

```
<input type="text" id="@Model.Id" name="@Model.Value">
```

I am trying

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Value, ?)
```

Any advice how to do the above input in razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Value, new { id = Model.Id, name = Model.Value})
```

Comment: Would something like this be viable? @Html.TextBoxFor(o => option.Value, new { id = option.Id, name = option.Id}). Notice I want the value field to contain the answer that is being passed from this textbox. even though the name is option.id

Comment: Well...yes and no.  You need to use the keyword `Model`.  The lambda doesn't matter, you can use whatever `m =>` you like, but if you've declared a `@model` in your view, you should use `Model`.

Comment: oh sorry i am in a foreach loop. hence model being renamed to option.

Comment: I tried this in asp.net core 2.2, and `name` doesn't take, but `id` does. I can set name in a tag-helper without issue.